# NodeJS: Abort request function inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a electron application that can download multiple pages on a website. I want to be able to stop downloading the pages whenever I hit the stop button by instantly terminating the function. I tried stopping the function by setting it to a new function but because downloading happens in a function loop it is not stopped (I am unsure if this approach would even stop the startDownload function).

Is there a way to easily stop the execution of a function, that does not stop the whole script?

Edit: If there isn't a way to stop the execution of the function, is there a way to send a message to and stop the NodeJS request?

Edit 2: NodeJS requests have an abort method, but I am unsure how to tell the function to abort the request?

```
startDownload('website.com');

startDownload(url) {
    var startAt = 0;
    var maxPages = 15;
    download(url, startAt, maxPages);
}

download(url, page, maxPages) {
    if (page == maxPages) { finishDownload(url); return; }
    request(url + '?p=' + page, (error, response, html) => {
        downloadPage(html);
        download(url, page + 1, maxPages);
    }).catch((error) => {
        finishDownload(url, 'Failed to download');
    });
}

finishDownload(url, error = undefined) {
    if (!error) {
        alert(url + ' finished downloading');
    } else {
        alert(url + error);
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '#stopDownload', function() {
    var downloadFunction = startDownload;
    startDownload = function() {return false};
    startDownload = downloadFunction;
    alert('download stopped by killing function');
});
```

Comment: Reassigning the function won't do anything to currently executing code.  You will have to find out if the async operations you're using have an ability to cancel or stop?  Or, if you just want to stop the loop at it's next iteration, you can set a flag that the loop checks before it calls `download()` again.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can stop by

```
var r = request({uri: 'http://stackoverflow.com'  }, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log('url requested ') ;
    if (!error){
        console.log(body);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

r.abort();
```

Comment: Where does the request function handle being aborted? I am having trouble finding the appropriate documentation for aborting requests.

Comment: took a request into variable and then r.abort(); will abort